# jQuery, passing selectors as option parameters

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm trying to build a simple jquery plugin that can take selectors as parameters. All of the examples I find expect more raw 'properties' (width, color, etc) than actual selectors. Are there any good ways to do this?

I found this article : [Passing jquery selector to sub-function within a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541362/passing-jquery-selector-to-sub-function-within-a-plugin)

But I'm still relatively confused.

The goal is kind of like this ...

```
        (function ($) {
            $.fn.demonstration = function (options) {

                var defaults = {
                    $selector: null
                };
                var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

                return this.each(function () {
                    alert($selector.attr('id'));
                });
            };
        })(jQuery);

        $('body').demonstration({ $selector: $('#canvas') });
```

Comment: What you've done is that I'd do, although I'd remove the skanky $ from the start of $selector (see my comment below :P), and probably set the default $selector value to $(this), instead of null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A selector is nothing more than a string. As long as you wrap any access to a jQuery() ($) call, people can pass in pretty much anything (a selector string, a jQuery object, a DOM element, etc.)

Edit: Saw you added code, in this case you should access it by `$(options.$selector).attr('id')`.

Out of curiosity, why the $ before selector?

Comment: Because that's what I see everyone else using. No idea why they use it. I'm javascript retarded and still learning it.

Comment: @Stacey & Matti: Some people use it to signify which of their variables hold jQuery objects. I hate it personally :P

Comment: Okay, I have a question. Is it possible to pass two values at once? Such that $('body').demonstration( 'selector', 'something else' ). My goal is to pass more than just one selector, however. Any ideas?

Comment: Since jQuery works well with lists (make sure your plugin does too, the .each is a good sign), just have people pass in one object (which you then access with $()). If people want to pass in many things, they can just pass a jQuery object with whatever elements they want.

Comment: My basic goal is a small event pool, where objects with non-form events can be submitted to the pool - and then when I need to trigger the event, I trigger it on the pool and it raises it on everything that has been added to the pool. Am I at least taking the semi-right approach to that, or am I way out in left field?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create a robust selection system, which jQuery already has. You would simply use their selectors to weed out which items you want to select. Check it out: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Well, I'm trying to write something that will let me call one place to trigger a named event on everything that has subscribed to the event.